# For access control at folder level, is SVN better than Git?

Tags: git, svn

We have been using SVN for long and the main reason is that it allows us to restrict access to different branches of the repository to different developers (Thru the authz file).

SVN is simple to understand and a few commands are all we need and has served us well over the years.

But I often wonder if it is a case of "ignore is bliss" that we have not moved to GIT when the whole world appears to be doing just that.

**EDITED**:
Based upon the many comments, and particularly that of IMSoP, the question is simply: Is there an equivalent of the SVN's authz functionality. Actually, my initial query was confusing as it related to branches. What I am looking at is to restrict access to specific folders in the repository to certain users only which is possible in SVN through the authz config file.

So, for those who are not aware of SVN, here is an example of the authz file:

```
 [repo1:/]
  user1 = rw

 [repo1:/folder1]
  user2 = rw
  user3 = r

 [repo1:/folder2]
  user3 = rw
```

So while user1 has complete access to the entire repository, user2 and user3 have access only to certain folders. Type of access is also possible to control as in read or read-write. **Can this be done in Git?**

I am extremely sorry for the initial language used which was confusing as pointed out. Can Git support the above functionality?

Comment: i do not think there is something like that in git. Consider that the design premises between svn and git are different. In git, you _own_ your local repo so not much point in writing some kind of restriction so _you_ are not able to get access to something you have locally. It _might_ be possible for a provider to setup some restriction at the branch level.... but once _another_ developer has it in their repo, it's not like there's one way you could restrict _them_ from sharing it anyway if they so wanted to do.... so I do not think it's something you will find around either,.

Comment: As currently written, this Question is a bit unfocussed, asking several questions, some of which are matters of opinion rather than fact ("a better choice" is always going to be subjective). There *is* a concrete question buried here ("is there an equivalent of the SVN's authz functionality") but it suffers from a bit of an X/Y problem - you haven't said what you specifically want to achieve. The idea of a "secret" branch that some developers can't even check out seems weird to me, so maybe the *underlying* requirement would be tackled a different way in a git ecosystem.

Comment: Personally yes I think in an enterprise environment SVN is better for is centralized structure. Git grew in popularity because it allowed people to have version control for hobby/open source projects that were less structured and also allows people to work offline and in a distributed way more easily. It did this despite how atrocious it is to work with (possibly only surpassed by Vim). With SVN it is harder for teams of people to work on similar things and then merge them back together later, especially if they're offline for a while.

Comment: @eftshift0 Please see my edited question. Would appreciate any comment.

Comment: @IMSoP  Please see my edited question. Would appreciate any comment.

Comment: Can this be done in git?: At which level? With the git svn importer? What should the outcome be? Same behaviour of the two applications? (then answer is no: git is not svn, the way they do version control is fundamental different - server controlled vs. distributed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [IMSoP notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74610195/for-access-control-at-branch-level-is-svn-better-than-git#comment131699967_74610195), the question as phrased can't really be answered, but the *embedded* question can:

Q: **Does Git have a way to keep people from reading particular committed files, via some access control mechanism?**
A: **No.**

That's all you need at this point: the capability simply doesn't exist—not in Git as implemented, and the *design* of Git makes this exceedingly hard to achieve at other levels, so that you generally won't find it in most Git hosting services either.  If you find some hosting service that does *claim* to offer it, be suspicious that their claim is at best overblown and that there are ways around it.  That's not guaranteed, but they'd have to have a very non-Git-oriented way to get at things, to provide a proper hermetic seal.

There is a related question:

Q: Do branches actually exist in Git?
A: No—not the kind you mean with SVN, anyway.

SVN branches have real substance to them.  (This is what makes them somewhat expensive to create, vs Git's super-cheap "branch" that costs just a few bytes.)  Git's notion of "branch" is very different.  There are totally-ephemeral analogues, which won't get you anywhere *because* they are ephemeral, and things that Git also calls *branch* that are unrelated to what you're thinking, which won't get you anywhere because they're unrelated.

#### Edit re edited question:

> Can [authz style access control] be done in Git?

No.  Git is, internally, a "content addressable" file system, with version control overlaid upon that.  To access content, Git *does not use a path name*, so path-name based access control is literally impossible.  If you're familiar with Unix-style "inode" based file systems, Git works by you presenting the inode number, and receiving the content.  You can simply look at every inode and read every piece of content, even if you can't open things by path name for some reason.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Would appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of restricting developers access to branches would be to create multiple remotes for the same repository. That way it would be possible for someone to work on a branch on "restricted-origin" which only a few developers have access to.

It would have to be pushed to the normal origin sooner or later though since it has to be merged.

If you only care about restricting making commits (or rather pushing) to a branch, then that is a feature supported by most git hosting services.

I'm afraid I can't be much help in the comparison between SVN and git, it has simply been to long since I used SVN last.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Would appreciate any comment.